# Linear Independence Without Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the vectors in the set $[(x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3),(z_1,z_2,z_3)]$ where each vector belongs to $R^3$ are linearly independent. Show that the vectors in the set $[(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2),(x_3,y_3,z_3)]$ are linearly independent. Can this problem be generalized for $R^n$ where $n$ is any positive integer? Please do not use any concept of matrices here, only use properties of vector spaces in general.

I may want to add that I tried but the correct mathematical procedure is not hitting me.

Comment: Can you show why you are interested in this problem? Seems a  little bit artificial to exchange components between vectors.

Comment: This problem came in an examination conducted by our college. I am not particularly interested in this problem because I don't find any beauty in it. I don't think I get the result.

Answer (score 0):

We prove if $[(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2),(x_3,y_3,z_3)]$ are linearly dependent, then  $[(x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3),(z_1,z_2,z_3)]$  is linearly dependent too.

WLOG, suppose $(x_1,y_1,z_1) = a(x_2,y_2,z_2) + b(x_3,y_3,z_3)$, then in order to find $c, d, e$ such that$c(x_1,x_2,x_3)+d(y_1,y_2,y_3)+e(z_1,z_2,z_3) =0$, we only need to find $c,d,e$ such that $c(x_2,x_3)+d(y_2,y_3)+e(z_2,z_3) =0$ since $$cx_1 + dy_1 + ez_1 = a(cx_2 +dy_2 + ez_2) + b(cx_3+dy_3 + ez_3)$$

Then with two equation and three variables, you can solve it.

This can be generalized for $R^n$, without using matrix concept, if you admit linear system with more variables than equations have non-zero solution

Comment: I am sorry I could not follow from "we only need to find c,d,e such that..." Could you take the pain of explaining a bit more? Thank you so much! I had so much trouble juggling with these 9 equations and finally going nowhere.

Comment: @AnonymousMaths Because the equation following "since", we automatically get $cx_1 + dy_1 + ez_1 = 0$ when $c(x_2,x_3)+d(y_2,y_3)+e(z_2,z_3) =0$

Comment: Okay, let me go over it again then. Thanks! Now, due to the symmetry, can I conclude that the reverse also holds?

Comment: @AnonymousMaths Yes of course you can

Comment: A curiosity just. How would you rate this question? I could not do it so obviously it was hard for me.

Comment: I think whether it's hard or not depends on what one has learned before. For a beginner this may be not easy, for someone who is familiar with linear system or matrix theory, this should not be hard

Comment: Yes I am a beginner, and we have not been taught matrix theory or linear equations till now. Thanks I have got the proof. Thank you very much.